# Remove encoding characters from http_build_query

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get a **JSON Array of Objects** and turn into a **HTTP query**.

The JSON is like this:

```
[
    {"name": "Silvia"},
    {"age": 24}
]
```

I need to turn into this:

```
?name=Silvia&age=24
```

I'm trying to use `http_query_params(), but its returning the query like this:

```
?0%5Bname%5D=Silvia&1%5Bage%5D=24
```

I tried to use `urldecode()` but not helped...

Here is my full code:

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($data['filters']);

$query = http_build_query($jsonArray, null, '&');

$url = $endpoint."?".$query;
```

Comment: What you _want_, requires a simple associative array. But what you have, is a numerically indexed array containing _objects_. So transform the latter into the former first.

Comment: Though if you turn the objects into arrays, you'll still have a multi-dimensional array. You'll need to flatten it, so it's just `['name'=>'Silvia', 'age'=>24]`. If you're passing a lot of objects, you might have better luck just passing the json itself.

Comment: And then you will have to work out where `$params` comes from, because it is not mentioned anywhere before you attempt to use it ??

Comment: The $params is the JSON Array, sorry

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will be the solution to your problem :)

```
$items = json_decode('[
    {"name": "Silvia"},
    {"age": 24}
]');

$count = 1;
$string = '';
foreach($items as $item)
{
    foreach($item as $key => $val)
    {   
        $char = ($count == 1) ? "?" : "&";
        $string .= $char . urlencode($key) . "=" . urlencode($val);
        $count++;
    }
}

echo $string;
```

This will be `?name=Silvia&age=24`

Comment: This completely neglects to apply URL encoding, should it be necessary for any of those parameter names or values.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building the query string manually let's use [`http_build_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) as we should. But first, let's flatten the original array;

```
$jsonString = '[
    {"name": "Silvia"},
    {"age": 24}
]';

$jsonArray = json_decode($jsonString, true); // true flag converts to array instead of object

$assoc_array = array();

foreach($jsonArray AS $arr){
    foreach($arr AS $key => $val) {
        $assoc_array[$key] = $val;
    }
}
```

This returns;

```
Array
(
    [name] => Silvia
    [age] => 24
)
```

Now make the query string;

```
$queryString = http_build_query($assoc_array);
echo urlencode($queryString); // you can actually skip this
```

which returns;

```
name%3DSilvia%26age%3D24
```

As you can see in [this example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/952be976155fd2af9e54eca37765299b3620eee1)

This is much more "portable" and you can make a function out of the array flattening method demonstrated.